# UINavigationView pop to root view controller problem

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uinavigationcontroller

I have two view controllers in my app. In first view I display core data objects. I have custom UIView with UILabel to do that. In second view I have action to add new core data objects. Both are embedded in UINavigationController, where first view is root view controller. When I add object I want to bring user back to root view, but it must contains new data.

I was trying to use .popToRootViewController() action but when I go back, my data wasn't updated. I have same data, as when I launched my app.

Code from SecondViewController

```swift
  private func saveCaffeineData(coffeeName: String, coffeeSelectedSize: String, coffeeCaffeineAmount: Double, coffeeshop: String, date: Date) {
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CaffeineData", in: managedContext)!
        let caffeineData = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        caffeineData.setValuesForKeys(["coffeeName" : coffeeName, "coffeeSize" : coffeeSelectedSize, "caffeineAmount" : coffeeCaffeineAmount, "coffeeShop" : coffeeshop, "date" : date])

        do {
        try managedContext.save()
            allCaffeineData.append(caffeineData)

            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Code from FirstViewController

```
lazy var todaySummaryView: TodaySummaryView = {
        let todaySummaryView = TodaySummaryView(todayCoffeeAmount: countTodayCaffeineAmount(), caffeineState: getCaffeineUserState()!)
        todaySummaryView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        todaySummaryView.backgroundColor = .white
        todaySummaryView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return todaySummaryView
    }()

    private func setupLayout() {
        title = "Dashboard"

        if caffeineData.count == 0 {
            view.addSubview(nothingView)
            view.addSubview(addDataButton)

            addDataButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCaffeine), for: .touchUpInside)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                nothingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
                nothingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
                nothingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                nothingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
                addDataButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                addDataButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
                addDataButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
                addDataButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
            ])
        } else {
            view.addSubview(dashboardScrollView)
            view.addSubview(addDataButton)

            addDataButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addCaffeine), for: .touchUpInside)

            dashboardScrollView.addSubview(dashboardScrollViewContentView)
            dashboardScrollViewContentView.addSubview(todaySummaryView)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                dashboardScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                dashboardScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                dashboardScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                dashboardScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

                dashboardScrollViewContentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollView.topAnchor),
                dashboardScrollViewContentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollView.leadingAnchor),
                dashboardScrollViewContentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollView.trailingAnchor),
                dashboardScrollViewContentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollView.bottomAnchor),
                dashboardScrollViewContentView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollView.centerXAnchor),

                todaySummaryView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollViewContentView.topAnchor, constant: 20),
                todaySummaryView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollViewContentView.centerXAnchor),
                todaySummaryView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollViewContentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
                todaySummaryView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardScrollViewContentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),

                addDataButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                addDataButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
                addDataButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
                addDataButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300)
            ])
        }
    }

    @objc private func addCaffeine() {
        let destinationViewController = SelectCoffeeTableViewController()

        navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "CaffeineData")

        do {
            caffeineData = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            setupLayout()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Something goes wrong! \(error.description)")
        }
    }

    private func countTodayCaffeineAmount() -> Float {
        var caffeineAmount = Float()

        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let todayDate = Date()
        let todayDay = calendar.component(.day, from: todayDate)
        let todayMonth = calendar.component(.month, from: todayDate)
        let todayYear = calendar.component(.year, from: todayDate)

        for caffeineRow in caffeineData {
            let caffeineDay = calendar.component(.day, from: caffeineRow.value(forKey: "date") as! Date)
            let caffeineMonth = calendar.component(.month, from: caffeineRow.value(forKey: "date") as! Date)
            let caffeineYear = calendar.component(.year, from: caffeineRow.value(forKey: "date") as! Date)

            if (todayDay == caffeineDay && todayMonth == caffeineMonth && todayYear == caffeineYear) {
                caffeineAmount += caffeineRow.value(forKey: "caffeineAmount") as! Float
            }
        }
        return caffeineAmount
    }

    private func getCaffeineUserState() -> CaffeineState? {
        var caffeineState: CaffeineState

        let caffeineAmount = countTodayCaffeineAmount()

        switch caffeineAmount {
        case 0..<200:
            caffeineState = .normal
        case 200..<300:
            caffeineState = .warning
        case 300...:
            caffeineState = .dangerous
        default:
            return nil
        }

        return caffeineState
```

Code from CustomView

```
//
//  TodaySummaryView.swift
//  Caffeinee
//
//  Created by Piotr Sirek on 11/06/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Piotr Sirek. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class TodaySummaryView: UIView {
    var todayCoffeeAmount: Float = 0.0
    var caffeineState: CaffeineState = CaffeineState.normal

    lazy var todayLabel: UILabel = {
        let todayLabel = UILabel()
        todayLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
        todayLabel.text = "Today"
        todayLabel.textColor = .white
        todayLabel.textAlignment = .center
        todayLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return todayLabel
    }()

    lazy var todayLabelView: UIView = {
        let todayLabelView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 74, height: 28))
        todayLabelView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        todayLabelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return todayLabelView
    }()

    lazy var todayStateLabel: UILabel = {
        let todayStateLabel = UILabel()
        todayStateLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .semibold)
        todayStateLabel.textColor = .black
        todayStateLabel.textAlignment = .left
        todayStateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        todayStateLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        return todayStateLabel
    }()

    lazy var caffeineAmountLabel: UILabel = {
        let caffeineAmountLabel = UILabel()
        caffeineAmountLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 45, weight: .heavy)
        caffeineAmountLabel.textAlignment = .left
        caffeineAmountLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        caffeineAmountLabel.text = "142"
        return caffeineAmountLabel
    }()

    lazy var caffeineUnitLabel: UILabel = {
        let caffeineUnitLabel = UILabel()
        caffeineUnitLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .heavy)
        caffeineUnitLabel.textAlignment = .left
        caffeineUnitLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        caffeineUnitLabel.text = "mg"
        return caffeineUnitLabel
    }()

    private func setupView() {
        self.addSubview(todayLabelView)
        self.addSubview(todayStateLabel)
        self.addSubview(caffeineAmountLabel)
        self.addSubview(caffeineUnitLabel)

        todayLabelView.addSubview(todayLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            todayLabelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 15),
            todayLabelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            todayLabelView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 28),
            todayLabelView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 74),

            todayLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: todayLabelView.centerXAnchor),
            todayLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: todayLabelView.centerYAnchor),
            todayLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26),
            todayLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),

            todayStateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: todayLabelView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            todayStateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            todayStateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
            todayStateLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor),

            caffeineAmountLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: todayStateLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 15),
            caffeineAmountLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 15),
            caffeineAmountLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -15),

            caffeineUnitLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: caffeineAmountLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            caffeineUnitLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
    }

    private func presentState(todayCoffeeAmount: Float, caffeineState: CaffeineState) {
        caffeineAmountLabel.text = "\(todayCoffeeAmount)"

        switch caffeineState {
        case .normal:
            todayLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.24, green:0.63, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0)
            todayStateLabel.text = "Your caffeine level is quiet good today. Keep it up!"
        case .warning:
            todayLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.96, green:0.68, blue:0.42, alpha:1.0)
            todayStateLabel.text = "Your caffeine now is near your daily limit. Be carefull!"
        case .dangerous:
            todayLabelView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.31, blue:0.31, alpha:1.0)
            todayStateLabel.text = "Your caffeine level is over your daily limit. Don’t drink any coffee for rest of the day."
        }
    }

    override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 340, height: 200)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    init(todayCoffeeAmount: Float, caffeineState: CaffeineState) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect())
        setupView()
        presentState(todayCoffeeAmount: todayCoffeeAmount, caffeineState: caffeineState)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a delegate protocol, or use notifications to update the first controller.
Here's an example how to use Delegates:

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func caffeineDataSaved(controller: SecondViewController)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
   weak var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate?

   private func saveCaffeineData(coffeeName: String, coffeeSelectedSize: String, coffeeCaffeineAmount: Double, coffeeshop: String, date: Date) {
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CaffeineData", in: managedContext)!
        let caffeineData = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

        caffeineData.setValuesForKeys(["coffeeName" : coffeeName, "coffeeSize" : coffeeSelectedSize, "caffeineAmount" : coffeeCaffeineAmount, "coffeeShop" : coffeeshop, "date" : date])

        do {
        try managedContext.save()
            allCaffeineData.append(caffeineData)
            self.delegate?.caffeineDataSaved(controller: self)

            navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

First, in `FirstViewController` class, declare `FirstViewController` as a delegate of `SecondViewController`. You can do this on `ViewDidLoad` or where ever you instantiated SecondViewController:

```
self.secondController.delegate = self
```

Now, In the `FirstViewController`, you need to implement the delegate method:

```
 func caffeineDataSaved(controller: SecondViewController) {
    //Update your view.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You’re my hero for today :)

Comment: Hey, I have a question, because it didn't work. How can I update my custom view? What I must to input inside caffeineDataSaved function.

Comment: First, make sure the new data is actually saved in the db. Second, Reload the view with the new data in the delegate method. you need to pass the new data to the TodaySummaryView. There are several methods to do this- either implement a function that updates the UI with new data, or override LayoutSubviews and do it there with a data object you pass.

Comment: In the FirstVieeController in delegate function I wrote todaySummaryView.todayCoffeeAmount = countTodayCaffeineAmount and todaySummaryView.caffeineState = getCaffeineUserState and nothing happen :(

Comment: I want to say thanks again. Today with cool head I implemented protocol with presetState() function and it works! I mark your answer as solved :)